# C++, симметричное шифрование

Tags: c++, шифрование

Хочу написать шифратор для файлов, интересуют симметричные шифрования, кроме xor. Желательно с ссылками на примеры.

Comment: Объясните, чем вам не нравится xor. практически все симметричные алгоритмы основаны на нем, просто по тому, что это наиболее удобная для шифрования операция. весь вопрос только в ключе шифрования. Современные, стойкие алгоритмы, вроде DES или AES являются фактически алгоритмами генерации ключа, а последняя и самая малозначительная операция в этих системах все та же xor. вместо xor конечно можно использовать сложение или вычитание по модулю, но это ничего не изменит

Answer (score 2):

Шифрование это как раз самая простая часть, ее даже писать самому не нужно. Для любого шифра существует так называемая "reference implementation". Это реализация шифра, обычно написанная на C, от авторов шифра. Для всех распространенных шифров reference implementation находится в public domain, то есть можете ее использовать как хотите и даже спасибо авторам необязательно говорить. Хорошим выбором являются AES, Twofish, Serpent, для них существуют масса реализаций на разных языках. После того, как вставите код в свою программу, обязательно проверьте шифр на "test vectors", которые также существуют для любого шифра. Это просто триады plaintext/key/ciphertext. Проверять по тестовым векторам нужно обязательно, потому что если есть хоть малейшая возможность ошибиться, то так оно и будет.

То есть алгоритм такой: допустим, хотите использовать Twofish. Набираете в гугле "twofish reference implementation", идете на сайт Шнайера, тащите оттуда все что нужно, и ваяете свою утилиту.

Проблемы у вас будут не с шифром. Для приличной программы шифрования файлов собственно шифр занимает в районе 0,5% кода и, как я уже сказал, писать его необязательно. Основные проблемы там совершенно в другом, и вы с ними, несомненно, встретитесь. Разработка формата файла (нетривиальная задача), управление ключами и проблема их верификации (очень нетривиальная задача), надежное удаление исходных файлов (еще более нетривиальная задача, которая во многих случаях вообще не решается). В общем, успехов.